# Error moving a certificate to remote server

Tags: iis-6

I am trying to obtain a certificate and move it to a remote server. It is a report server which requires its own certificate for SSL but is not running IIS.

I have a server running IIS 6 so i created a fake website to create a csr, obtained a certificate from a 3rd party, then processed and installed the cert on the fake website.  I want to then move the certificate to a remote server. when it asks for the server name and credentials i supply them, hit next, then get the error, 'class not registered'. any ideas?

Thanks
-Ed

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but what is asking for the server name and credentials?  What format does the report server need the Key&Certificate in.  PKCS#11, PEM bundle?

Since I am not sure what you are doing let me suggest this.  Open up the MMC, and add the Certificates snap-in, and point it at the Computer Account on the IIS.  Once you have that open, you should see and export the certificate in *Personal* folder.